# facing segfault in c program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, extern

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pointer-array-extern question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385850/pointer-array-extern-question)

We have two files:

file1.c

```
int myarray[10];
```

file2.c

```
extern int *myarray;

void foo()
{
    myarray[0]=10;
}

void main() 
{
    foo();
}
```

This program gives a segmentation fault. However If we change the `extern int *myarray` to `extern int myarray[]` , the program works.

Please explain. Thanks!