# using extern with different type but same name variable in C

Tags: c, extern

I have `int a[]` in one C file. Now in another .c file I have `extern int *a` .

I need to know what will be the behavior if I try to access variable `a` in second file and why?
What all problems would occur?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.actually both have same name 'a'

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behaviour.  So anything might happen.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit as to why undefined behavior?

Comment: @vaibhavshukla: Because the standard says it is.  (See section 6.2.7 of C99.)  On a more practical level, see some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385850/pointer-array-extern-question.

Comment: What if I include first file in second? What will be outcome? Linking error or compiler error?

Comment: @vaibhavshukla: You could try it... ;)

Comment: :) I definitely will. But still want to be shown some more light to the concept before coming to conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the file(declaration) twice or declared variable named a, then there may be error redefinition of a;

when i tried the above compiler shows error :

```
conflicting types for a;
//previous definition in other file...
```

Comment: @dinesh: I dnt think so bcoz extern keyword says that its a declaration not definition or say when we say extern, it means somewhere in other file variable has been define, so how come redefinition error?